# Render Dialog Component in Loop several times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I´m currently experimenting with React and Material-UI.

I have a component which includes another component. Inside the `render()` I´m looping over a pseudo array which renders a `<FormDialog />`component.

```
  <ul>
     {tableContent.map((item, i) => 
       <li key={i}>{item.x}
          <FormDialog/>
      </li>
  )}
  </ul>
```

When inspecting the DOM using REACT-TOOLS I can see ofcourse that the Dialog component is 3 times there.

[image: DOM]

I´m currently asking myself if this is bad practices and will lead to heavy performance issues in a real world example when I render the Component around 20-50 times.

**In case this is a Problem**

What I really like is that the Dialog component is just working out of box and does not need any other component "action" to be opend or closed. Therefore I don´t see an option to keep the great self consistent functionality of the Dialog Component, when this example would be bad practise and bring me big performance issues.

This is the dialog component, just copied from the Material-UI demo:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';

export default class FormDialog extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
  };

  handleClickOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={this.handleClickOpen}>
          Open form dialog
        </Button>
        <Dialog
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
        >
          <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Subscribe</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText>
              To subscribe to this website, please enter your email address here. We will send
              updates occasionally.
            </DialogContentText>
            <TextField
              autoFocus
              margin="dense"
              id="name"
              label="Email Address"
              type="email"
              fullWidth
            />
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
              Subscribe
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**So what am I asking you**

1) I would like to know if what i described is bad and should be avoided in a real world example

2) What easy options would I have to keep the self consistent functionality of the component, but make it **the right way**. I would really like to avoid to hold the open state of the Dialog Component in the parent component.

Comment: why do you need multiple Dialogs. IMO you should have a single `<Dialog>` component, multiple buttons to open that dialog. And you can pass some props to the dialog so that you can change the content inside the dialog according to the props.

Comment: In general you are right. Actually I don´t need several **different** Dialogs, but I need a `Dialog`in each row. I know that I could just render buttons in each row, but this would lead me to keep track of the `Dialog state` in the parent component, which I don´t really like.

Comment: how much data does state of each dialog will have, just `open` or more stuff?

Comment: There will not be that much data. In fact there will be 3-6 input fields to enable the user to enter some data which will be then passed up to parent component.

Comment: in that case you can just save the values of those input fields in state of your dialog. I guess it will be lost on dialog close. If you want to avoid that you should use redux for managing state.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn´t understand you properly. But saving the user input is not my problem. I´m asking for a good aproach how to make the app efficient and keeping the simplicity of self consistent  component

Comment: mapping multiple dialogs should not be problem.